# ssh login with mail address

Tags: ssh, email, ldap, pam

I have an **Ldap Server** configured an running and another server listen to this users database. (Ldap client)
I need to force users login on ssh with user as email

> (dc: mail=myself@anymail.com)

and not default username.

> (uid:)

example:

> **ssh -l user@anymail.com 192.168.0.100**

Is this possible?

Comment: This isn't configured in SSH but rather your LDAP client (libnss_ldap.conf to recognize the user, pam_ldap.conf for authorization).

Comment: I added these parameter ( pam_login_attribute mail )
to booth files.. should I do anything else?

Comment: done
the trick isto remap 
nss_map_attribute uid mail

Comment: If you found a solution, post it below as an answer.

Comment: ok I did it
the trick is to map uid to mail
nss_map_attribute uid mail

Comment: Post your solution's detail as an answer, not a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone like me looking this answer and skipped reading the comments:

You need to modify the /etc/ldap.conf (in client):

1. Uncomment **pam_login_attribute uid** and change it into **pam_login_attribute mail**
2. Add **nss_map_attribute uid mail**

credits to op